# Как соединить две таблицы БД

Tags: база-данных, sql

Есть две таблицы:

```
Sp:
 - kod (string 10) - код предприятия уникальнй идентификатор
 - Name (string 60) - название предприятия
 - Kod_insp (string 7) - код инспектора

Insp:
 - kod (string 7) - код инспектора
 - name (string 30) - ФИО инспектора
```

К первой таблице присоединить инспекторов из второй таблицы, учитывая такую возможность, что в первой таблице могут встречаться коды инспекторов, которые не присутствуют во второй.

Comment: Лучше всего для начала почитать теорию T-SQL, вопрос действительно очень простой.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT *
FROM Sp
LEFT JOIN Insp ON Insp.kod = Sp.Kod_insp
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь